# Hide Delete Button in Gridview if RowID links to Foreign Key

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, vb.net, gridview

VB.NET - I've found other questions related to this, but none specifically to my situation. I'm dealing with only two tables - "task" and "task_run."

I have a Gridview with rows listing certain "tasks." They come from the "task" table and each task has a "tsk_id." I want to have a delete button for each task (row) and only want the delete button visible for that row if the task does not have a run associated with that task from the "task_run" table. (i.e. I do not want the user to be able to delete that task if it has already been run.)

table1 - "task"
PKY = "tsk_id"

table2 - "task_run"
PKY = "run_id"
FKY = "run_tsk_id"

I assume I need to have a template field in my gridview and have the delete button conditionally show based on whether there are rows in the run table associated with that particular task Id, but am stuck on how to do this. Hopefully this makes sense. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first get the task_Id from Task_run table accordingly user if exist otherwise return zero value , and placed this Task_Id in gridview on Label or textbox or hidden field with visible=false property if you not showing to user,
use this command for checking Task have already run or not by user.

```
  SELECT        ext.* , ISNULL((SELECT top 1 run_tsk_id
 FROM task_run WHERE run_tsk_id = ext.tsk_id),0) AS CheckId
    FROM          task  ext
```

then use the gridview RowDataBound event to hide or show the delete button conditionally, code as.

```
  Protected Sub Grid_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim lblCheckId As Label = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("lblCheckId"),Label)
        Dim deleteButton As Button = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("btnDelete"), Button)
        If CInt(lblCheckId.Text) > 0 Then
            deleteButton.Visible = False
        Else
            deleteButton.Visible = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! Where does that first line of code (the sql statement) go? In a separate datasource? thanks again!

Comment: sorry i don't clearly understand your question plz explain it.

Comment: you can use this sql statement in store procedure or sql command directly , and call this from page load event of the page where u populate gridview .if you ask some else then clearly ask , and share your code where you have problem,

Comment: sorry. I'm working on this right now, actually. You said the Task_id needs to go in gridview on label or textbox.. I chose to put a label on the gridview to hold the task run count. I also used your vb code you provided, and it's throwing an exception saying it cannot convert the label to an integer. Do you know the solution for this? I must be missing something obvious. Thanks!

Comment: first comment this lines  'If CInt(lblCheckId.Text) > 0 Then
       '     deleteButton.Visible = False                  and then execute again to check whether you grid show value for count label or not , make sure your count label should not null value , thatswhy its thrown an exception ,

Comment: Yep, that is the problem. Count value is not showing in label. Must be null. How do I make sure the count label should not null value?

Comment: you should use this line of code for sql statment  "  SELECT        ext.* , ISNULL((SELECT top 1 run_tsk_id
 FROM task_run WHERE run_tsk_id = ext.tsk_id),0) AS CheckId
    FROM          task  ext  "     in this code the CheckId attribute assign to count label when u bind with grid ,

Comment: which select statement you are using for getting value from db ?

Comment: Problem solved. I didn't even have my label binded to the sql data source. Sorry, I'm a blonde ;) Thank you so much for all of your help!!

Comment: your welcome ;   if u satisfied from my answer then accept this answer. regard

Comment: you are a blonde ; what u mean , ..........

Answer (score 0):

If you already have your tables in a DataSet (`ds` say), you can add a relation via

```
ds.Relations.Add(name, parentColumn, childColumn, createConstraints)
```

For example:

```
ds.Relations.Add(
    name, 
    ds.Tables("task").Columns("tsk_id"), 
    ds.Tables("task_run").Columns("run_tsk_id"), 
    True)
```

Alternatively, you could add a "task_run_count" as a property of table task via a subquery:

```
SELECT ..., 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM task_run WHERE run_tsk_id = task.tsk_id) AS [task_run_count] 
FROM task
```

Answer (score 0):

The DataSource which you are binding to to the grid should also have Task run count. Then you can use the RowDataBound event to show or hide the button.

```
Protected Sub Grid_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim taskRunCount As Integer = Convert.ToInt16(e.Row.Cells(0).Text) ''The Cells[0] should be which ever column you have Task run count
        Dim deleteButton As Button = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("DeleteButton"), Button)
        If taskRunCount > 0 Then
            deleteButton.Visible = False
        Else
            deleteButton.Visible = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```